# Having issue when return result from promise (Im not able to use await) because it is inside a forEach

Tags: typescript, vue.js, foreach, zendesk

Current situation:
I'm having a code that is handling API. And im trying to map it and return it as a string.

```
const C = this.functionA('ID_123').then(function(value) { 
   console.log("JR TEST 3", value.user.name); 
   return value.user.name;
});
```

The code above is to call the function and under 'JR TEST 3' console it return this result which is correct: `JR TEST 3 USERNAME`

But when I use

```
const C = this.functionA('ID_123').then(function(value) { 
   console.log("JR TEST 3", value.user.name); 
   return value.user.name;
});
console.log('JR TEST 4', C);
```

This will return me this: [image]

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: .then() returns a promise again, so you basically have two choices deal with the result as in the first example or use async/await syntax `await this.function(...`. If you can provide more info on how/where you want to use that mapped value, it will make it easier to suggest exact change. Meanwhile reading this might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining

Comment: Sorry I forget to mentioned: I cannot use await because that code i called is inside a forEach @ggat

Comment: then easiest is to change forEach to `for` or `for...of` loop and use `await` syntax

Comment: Consider asking the right question, then you'll be able to get the right answer. This totally depends on what happens in your code. async/await is much better suited to work with loops. It's possible to do everything it does with raw promises but this may be not straightforward at all. You may want to reconsider the reasons you don't use async/await, probably they are not valid enough.